# Обработка маршрутов в nodejs express

Tags: node.js, get, javascript

Добрый день!

Есть проблема с обработкой GET запросов в фреймворке express.

У меня есть обработка путей такого вида:

```
app.get('/projects/:project', routes.project);
app.get('/projects/:project/:presentation', routes.presentation);
app.get('/projects/:project/:presentation/:image', routes.image);
```

и есть картинки, которые хранятся по этому пути:

```
/projects/TestP/test/404page_03.png
```

Этот путь совпадает с 3м вариантом обработки пути и по этому сервер пытается обработать картинку как GET запрос страницы. Из за этого картинка не грузится

Как можно сделать так, что бы img загружались нормально, и при этом не нужно было менять путь до картинок?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В третьем правиле ввести дополнительную проверку

```
app.get('/projects/:project/:presentation/:image', function(req, res) {
  if (req.params.image=='404page') {
    routes.render404(req, res); //генерим страницу 404
  }
  else {
    routes.image(req, res);
  }
}
```

(код просто для демонстрации идеи, не проверен)